# ResultSet method "last" is this an optimal way?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have this java code which does this

```
ResulSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    .... //do regular processing

    if (rs.last()) {
       //do last record processing
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use: [isLast()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#isLast()) instead.

Be warned, not all the JDCB drivers support this feature. Obviously you have to check it with your installation.

Most major DB work fine.

The fixed code should look like this.

```
if( rs.isLast() ) { 
   // do last record processing
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would declare the variables that are retrieved from the query outside the loop, and then do the "last record processing" after the loop.

```
ResulSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
long primaryKey;

while (rs.next()) {
    primaryKey = rs.getLong(1);
    .... //do regular processing
}

// Do last record processing.
System.out.println("last primary key = " + primaryKey);
```

Answer (score 2):

No: rs.last() will actually send the cursor to the last row in the ResultSet, which is definitely not what you want to do. You would only ever process at most 2 rows (first and last) from the result set.